# Tabular output in Fortran, that is robust against unexpected values?

Tags: fortran

In Fortran, is it possible to print data in a tabular manner, without losing information, when more space is needed than specified?

For instance consider the program

```
! format.f90
program main
  real(8) :: arr(5)
  arr = [0.0, 1.111, 22.22, 333.3, 444444444444444444.44]
  print '(F10.3)', arr
end program main
```

Then by default the output for the last entry will be replaced by stars, indicating the lack of space.

```
>> ifort format.f90 -o format.bin
>> ./format.bin
     0.000
     1.111
    22.220
   333.300
**********
```

By comparison, C-style format specifiers automatically increase the column width when required, e.g.

```
// format.c
#include <stdio.h>
int main () {
  double arr[5] = {0.0, 1.111, 22.22, 333.3, 444444444444444444.44};
  for(int i=0; i<5; i++) {
    printf("%10.3f\n", arr[i]);
  }
}

>> gcc format.c -o format.bin
>> ./format.bin
     0.000
     1.111
    22.220
   333.300
444444444444444416.000
```

Is it possible to obtain such behavior in Fortran with built-in features?

### Options, that don't fulfill the requirements

**G descriptor.** The `G` descriptor allows reliably outputting data in a tabular well-readable format and automatically adds exponentials when needed. However, it also wastes space if the exponentials are *not* needed and it doesn't line up the comma. For example, when switching `F10.3` for `G11.4,"¶"` (paragraph sign added for emphasis):

```
>> ifort format.f90 -o format.bin
>> ./format.bin
  0.000    ¶
  1.111    ¶
  22.22    ¶
  333.3    ¶
 0.4444E+18¶
```

**Building a formatting API based on the `F0` specifier.** The specifier `F0.3` would allow variable-width output, but doesn't allow specifying a minimum width. This could be solved using a wrapper function akin to [leftpad](https://www.theregister.co.uk/2016/03/23/npm_left_pad_chaos/), but a built-in or widely-used solution would be preferable for a better chance of actually being used in a codebase. As an example:

```
! format.f90
program main
  real(8) :: arr(5)
  integer :: i
  arr = [0.0, 1.111, 22.22, 333.3, 444444444444444444.44]

  ! more complicated print statement, because 'float2char'
  ! cannot be 'elemental' due to needing the 'alloctable' property.
  print '(A)', (float2char('(F0.3)', 10, arr(i)), i=1,5)

contains

  function float2char(format, width, value) result(r)
    character(:), allocatable :: r
    character(*), intent(in) :: format
    integer, intent(in) :: width
    real(8), intent(in) :: value

    character(64) :: buffer ! better: calculate size from value?

    write(buffer, format) value
    allocate(character(max(width, len_trim(buffer))) :: r)
    r(:) = trim(buffer)  ! (:) needed to prevent reallocation in recent compilers
    r(:) = adjustr(r)
  end function float2char

end program main

>> ifort format.f90 -o format.bin
>> ./format.bin
      .000
     1.111
    22.220
   333.300
444444452740661248.000
```

Comment: Why is F0.3 not a built in feature? It is perfectly standard Fortran.

Comment: @IanBush `F0.3` is builtin but, on its own, doesn't provide tabular output. `F10.3` provides tabular output, but nothing useful at all if the data doesn't fit in 10 columns.  By comparison `printf` is builtin in C *and* provides tabular output, while automatically relaxing the "tabular" property, if the data doesn't fit. `F0.3` can be used to build a function or subroutine, that provides a formatted representation of "10 or more" characters.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, so in Fortran the fixed-width edit descriptors really are FIXED width. Sometimes useful, often annoying.

One thing you can do is to use the `G` edit descriptor, which is similar to `%g` in C, namely that it switches to scientific format when the number is large or small. That allows very large or small values to fit in a fixed width field. Note however that with `G` editing the `d` is the number of significant digits, not the number of digits after the decimal point as with `F` editing. Also it leaves space at the end for the exponent even if the number is in the range that no exponent is needed.

Your example could look like

```
! format.f90
program main
  real(8) :: arr(4)
  arr = [0.0, 1.111, 222222222222.222, 3.333]
  print '(F10.3)', arr
  print *, 'With G edit'
  print '(G10.4)', arr
end program main
```

with output

```
     0.000
     1.111
**********
     3.333
 With G edit
 0.000    
 1.111    
0.2222E+12
 3.333
```

Comment: It ca be useful, but it doesn't provide tabular output in most cases. For instance, where with `F10.3` the number `222.2` would print as `␣␣␣222.200`, with `G10.4` it would print as `␣␣␣␣␣␣222.2`, while `1.111` prints as `␣␣␣␣␣␣1.111`, such that the comma is not aligned to the same column.